# Need some advice on dates and culture

Tags: c#, date, culture

We have some legacy code that can't really be altered which "forces" the user to enter a date in MM/dd/yyyy format through ValidationExpression and a regex on the text field.

However, the C# code will be expecting the date in either MM/dd/yyyy or dd/MM/yyyy depending on the region.

I need to format the entered date into the region specific date.

Any ideas?

So far I've tried `DateTime enteredDate = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDateTextBox.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` but that returns as error stating that "09/04/2013" is not a recognised date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` with `null`.

Comment: Still getting "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Comment: It worked for me. Are you sure that `StartDateTextBox.Text` is exactly how you posted it here (09/04/2013)? Try hardcoding that value into `ParseExact` and see if it works.

Comment: Wait, the entered date is 9/4/2013 but why would that make a difference.  It works when I enter 09/04/2013 but why?

Comment: It's because your format string expects double digits for both the month and the day. I would look closely at the options you can use in the format string to allow for leading 0s. I don't know of any off the top of my head though.

Comment: Fair enough.  There have been some very dopey architectural decisions in this thing.  Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. There is an overload (I think) of `DateTime.Parse` that takes multiple possible formats as a parameter.

Comment: I changed the format to be "M/d/yyyy and it seems to work.  Though the underlying architecture still needs to be fixed me thinks